# javascript validation of the elements

Tags: javascript

I am running a code for my validatio where i am facing some issues

I have created a function to validate but based upon my html a little bit help is needed

Here it is:

My HTML code look alike

```
<div class="el-form-item">
                           <label for="streetAddress" class="el-form-item__label">Street Address</label>
                           <div class="el-form-item__content">
                              <div class="el-input">
                                 <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="el-input__inner validate">
                              </div>
                              
                           </div>
                        </div>
```

here is the validation Function

```
function validate(){     
    
   var validateElements = document.getElementsByClassName("validate");
    
    var inputs = Array.prototype.filter.call(validateElements,function(element){
        return element.nodeName === 'INPUT';
    });
    
  
    
    for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i ++ ){
        var input = inputs[i];
        if(input.value.length == 0){
            // generic placeholder
            input.placeholder = "kindly enter value";
            // error class 
            input.classList.add("err");
            // focus on the input [ optional ]
            console.log(input.closest('.el-form-item__label'));
            input.closest('.el-form-item__label').classList.add('err'); // error happening here 
            input.focus();
            // break the loop [ optional ]
            break;
        }
    }
    
}
```

two things i am trying to do here

i want to cover the label also to `red` which is defined in the `.err` class
and also want to place the error just underneath the input element instead of inside the placeholder.

i posted my code code above, please guide

i hope the making this validation function as mixin so i can use in my vueJS app, if anyone can guide with that, would be much much appreciated

i am trying to include inputs first and then plan to bring other form elements with this.

Comment: `closest` retrieves the direct parent path only, it doesn't find a sibling of a parent. It looks like you could use `input.closest('.el-form-item__content').previousElementSibling.;` to refer the label element.

Comment: i created a fiddle, but its not working `https://jsfiddle.net/d8j7h0qz/`

Comment: It works nicely, when you use the provided selector `.el-form-item__content` instead of your own selector.

Comment: saying works nicely does not make it work, can you show a fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kosx2bjz/